# Like operator in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @paging as varchar(max)
    set @paging = 'A'
 if @paging is null Or @paging =''
    set @paging = 'where ttmo_supp =''tt&MO'''  
    else 
    set  @paging = 'where ttmo_supp =''tt&MO'' and Name like '+''''+ @paging +'%'''+''
```

when i execute my front end code , it is throwing error stating that "incorrect syntax error near tt".

Comment: Edit your question and show all your code (or a simplified version of it).  Include a print out of the that you are executing.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @paging as varchar(max)
    set @paging = 'A'
 if @paging is null Or @paging =''
    set @paging = 'where ttmo_supp =''tt&MO'''  
    else 
    set  @paging = 'where ttmo_supp =''tt&MO'' and Name like '+''''+ @paging +'%'''+''

Select @paging
```

You forgot @ symbol in IF statement after the Or on your variable.

Results

where ttmo_supp ='tt&MO' and Name like 'A%'

Updated with procedure

```
Create Procedure SP_AlphabeticPaging @paging VarChar(Max)
As
Begin
  if @paging is null Or @paging =''
    set @paging = 'where ttmo_supp =''tt&MO'''  
  else 
    set  @paging = 'where ttmo_supp =''tt&MO'' and Name like '+''''+ @paging +'%'''+''

  Select @paging
End
Go

EXEC SP_AlphabeticPaging 'A'
-- Result
-- where ttmo_supp ='tt&MO' and Name like 'A%'
EXEC SP_AlphabeticPaging ''
-- Result
-- where ttmo_supp ='tt&MO'
```

Comment: Thanks , but @ is present in my code , It is passing the values correctly but when i execute the SP it is throwing error .                                      EXEC [HAD].[SP_AlphabeticPaging] 'where ttmo_supp=''tt&MO'' and Service_Name like ''A%'''

Comment: I included the create procedure statement too.  This works fine for me